# How to share data between a main application and a background task?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

My application is using a background task to update the Live Tile. The background task is written on separate project in the same solution as the main application, and the namespace of the background task and the main application are different.

I would like the background task to have access to the main application's data so that the background task can update the Live Tile.

What is the way to achieve that?

Thanks
EitanB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the background task could execute even when the application is not running, your best bet would be to deposit the information of interest to the background task in some sharable data repository. [ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) would be a pretty lightweight option.

Comment: Hi Jim,
Thanks for your answer.
Is there an advantage of using LocalSettings vs. using LocalFolder or is it just a matter of preference?
Eitan

Comment: LocalSettings is more lightweight - name/value pair, but restricted in size.  With LocalFolder you'd use file I/O to write whatever you want to the file.